# Subclassing or External class for advanced view modification in MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

This is generally theoretical question about better practcies when creating advanced operation within the view in MVC.

Example:

I want to have view which adds to itself colored subviews based on given characters.
A is green, B - yellow, C - blue etc. Width of each subview scaled proportionally. Ex: I is thiner than W.

It also has pan gesture recogniser which changes spacing between generated subviews.

It also remembers given string.

I know that example is strage, but the question is:

Is it better to subclass view and add needed methods and params to it

or

Use Decorator Pattern and create new object which take reference to the view in which it would peform actions
?

I hope I am clear here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with decorator pattern, which means *Create new object which take reference to the view in which it would peform actions*.

And I would add separate decorator for every function you specified.

You won't violate single responsibility principle (S from SOLID) that way.